# How to solve this cmake issue with c++ code?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have compiled program with cmake.The cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 
project (clustering)

IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    SET(LIB_SUFFIX "")
ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    SET(LIB_SUFFIX 64)
ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

find_package(Eigen2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen2_INCLUDE_DIR})

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel."
      FORCE)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
    set(LIB_NAME clusteringd)
else(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
    set(LIB_NAME clustering)
endif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")

file(GLOB LIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")
file(GLOB LIB_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")

#add_library (${LIB_NAME}-s STATIC ${LIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS} ${LIB_SOURCES})
add_library (${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${LIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS} ${LIB_SOURCES})

install(
    TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}
)

#install(
#    TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}-s
#    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib${LIB_SUFFIX}
#)

install(
    FILES ${LIB_PUBLIC_HEADERS}
    DESTINATION include/${LIB_NAME}
)
```

The problem is that in my folder /clusteringmaster/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/ I have two folders CompilerIdC and CompilerIdCXX,both of them have exe file.As Sergey pointed out exe should be located in bin directory.When I list my CmakeFile

```
2.8.12.2        cmake.check_cache                CMakeOutput.log  Makefile2       progress.marks
clustering.dir  CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake  CMakeTmp         Makefile.cmake  TargetDirectories.txt
```

From the authors tutorial

### Build

```
You will need the Eigen2 library (libeigen2-devel) and CMake (only tested under Linux). 

    $ mkdir release
    $ cd release
    $ cmake ../
    $ make
```

Should I write cmake  -- build /home/milenko/clusteing-master/release?

I have not worked with cmake before,how should I solve this confusion?

Comment: So what is the problem? Is any error message or what?

Comment: According to cmake file you should search for result in /clusteringmaster/build/bin/ (SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin))

Comment: @Sergey I don'think it is an error,just I do not have any bin folder.I will further edit my question.

Comment: Then just re-read documentation about what cmake is. It is build project generator - so you forget to build your project after you've generated it. Do it with 'cmake --build .'

Comment: There is no confusion. 'cmake --build <path>' will call native build tool for which you've generated. In your case it will be 'make'.

Comment: @ Sergey Yes,but then I get [100%] Built target clustering at command line.After that everything is same in build directory,no bin folder!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83964/discussion-between-richard-rublev-and-sergey).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One item is that should use the cmake variable `${PROJECT_NAME}` as the target name for the `add_library` command. (Your project name is specified as "clustering" because of the `project (clustering)` statement.) To get a `d` suffix for the debug configuration build, use `set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)`. I also like to set the output directory variables using

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

(I will even set the `_DEBUG` and `_RELEASE` variants, but this may cause problems when you are first getting started, so I would wait before doing that.)

Comment: I apologize. I was wrong--you do have a project command at the top of your CMakeLists.txt--I must have missed it when it scrolled out of the frame. Your project command is ``project (clustering)``. I will edit my answer.